# How can an application load a DLL without its name?

Tags: windows, debugging, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I have disassembled a VB6 application that calls a function in a DLL library, but I can't find any reference to the DLL in the disassembly.  How can the calling code load this DLL?  It is dynamically linked, as I can observe the effects of removing and replacing the DLL.

I'm using IDA Pro Free, the calling application is a VB6 app, and the DLL is a plain Win32 DLL that I suspect was created using C or C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your application in [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_Exports_Viewer.htm), it will show you all the DLLs linked.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "*can't find any reference*"? you don't see the string of the dll name? 
you don't see the code who calls the dll?
You can put a break point in the dll and see the callstack that leads to the VB6 app.

Comment: Yes, I mean I can't find any code that refers to the dll, i.e. I don't see the string of the dll name, or the code that calls the dll.

Comment: how does the stacktrace looks (when the dll is in a breakpoint)?

Comment: I'm still getting there, I haven't got a proper debugging setup yet.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a COM DLL, it may well be looking it up via GUID instead of name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched for the Unicode version of the DLL name too?  The application that loads the DLL might be built using wide characters.